# Checking each stage results in post - Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, error-handling, jenkins-pipeline

I have a piepline that is performing a number of prep, automated testing and tear-down steps.  I'd like to catch errors in the stages and let the entire pipeline run (catchError w/ setting buildResult to 'SUCCESS' allows me to do that part).   Once all of the stages are complete, I'd like to evaluate the status of each stage and determine if I'd like the build to be marked as failed or not.

Is there any way to loop through the results of each stage in the pipeline during either a final step or in post/always?

Comment: Couldn't you just store the stage name in a list/map while you are catching the error?

Comment: @smelm, while I _could_ cache the values of the various stages in a map, it is clear that such a cache already exists in the project object model somewhere.  Without that information, Jenkins wouldn't be able to display it in the UI.  I was hoping that the existing cache was already available (many through the currentBuild object).